# Yii in what controller to put specific action

Tags: php, yii

This is more a structure question and I would like to here different opinions...

Having the following situation (which is common)

[image]

This is like the detail page of an item out of `Table 1`, on the first tab we have just a dump of all fields of this row.

In the second (and third) tab we have all items linked to this item (they both have a HAS_MANY relation).

So now the 'Add item' button should it:

A. Go to the `Table2Controller` since I then have a nice structure that my `Table2Model` is only called from my Table2Controller

or

B. Call my `Table2Model` from my `Table1Controller`

Postive about A.:
- All my functions where I add items in `Table2` are called in my `Table2Controller`, so I can make most code generic

Positive about B.:
- More easy to find read the code since everything on this screen can be found in my `Table1Controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case, its more important to split your templates in logical parts. By doing that, you will be able to use your templates like "snippets". In that way, ill put all actions of one "page" into one controller. Example: An AdminController and an UserController maybe will load the same template like:

```
/**
 * Action show in userController
 */
public function actionShow(){

    $this->render('/user/item'); 
}
```

This function will use the same templates, but its the adminController

```
/**
 * Action in adminController
 *
 * @param int $userId
 */
public function actionShowUserDetails($userId){

    $this->render('/user/item', array('user' =>  User::model()->findByPk($userId))); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use static methods?. For example, in an action of Table2Controller you can have the next:

```
$table1Model=new Table1Model();
```

Then you can access al the properties and methods in table1 like this

```
$table1Model->property1="Hello";
$table1Model->property2="Goodbye";
$table1Model->save();
```

Other thing you can do is to call directly a method in Table1Controller without init the Controller1. For example:

```
Table1Controller::method1InController1($param1,$param2);
```

Good luck

Comment: Using STATIC Methods in Yii-MVC is ridiculous. Like in most MVC-Patterns. Remember, Yii-Models are not singleton!

Comment: Hi lin, if I undestand you, you say that MVC should not to use Static methods. I think you talking about the "Table1Controller::method1InController1" because if you say to me that you don't use multiples model in a controller, I'm  very disagree with you. About using static methods, in wonderful land and in theory you must to avoid them, but in real world when your production is very important for your life you use them. In my programs, I don't use Controllers like a static method (but other pals do that and theirs Yii applications work). Ridiculous is a bad word, don't use it, please.

Comment: There should be no Static function declaired in your Model, Controller and for sure .. View. There is absolutely no need for this. Helpers, Libs, Components and native PHP-Functions are holding STATIC Methods, but not the Pattern.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong when I was talking about static methods. But you can call a method of other controller in a controller. For example
        Yii::import('application.controllers.ConsolaController');
        ConsolaController::actionVector();
Will work. You can get more info about that in http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6471-call-another-controllers-action/ 

Indeed, it's not a good practice but you can use it if you need it. I think it's better to do this instead of repeat code. You have reason when you talk about no declare a method as STATIC into a Controller.